# javascript currying parameters with .bind() method

Tags: javascript, parameters, bind, apply, currying

I'm examining a code from Kyle's Simpson book "You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes" and stuck on a code example, which is written below.

Could anybody explain in plain how bar variable after executing `var bar = foo.bind(null, 2);` piece of code saves "a" parameter as 2 and where it keeps that saved parameter, and why parameters is not overridden when `bar(3);` code executes?

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
  console.log("a:" + a + ", b:" + b);
}

foo.apply(null, [1, 10]);

var bar = foo.bind(null, 2);
bar(3);
```

Comment: It's in the definition of `bind`: *The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of **arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.*** It's simply what it does. How exactly it does it internally is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: While debugging i've found that i can access bar params via prototypes by executing `bar.call('BoundArgs')` code.

Comment: Can you demonstrate what exactly the result of that is and how you can "access" the parameters that way?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It cannot be accesed by code i've written earlier. 
I meant that i can see bound arguments to bar function in the window object. I've attached a sreenshot below.
[screenshot](https://image.ibb.co/eNxFmG/Screen_Shot_2017_10_11_at_15_01_32.png)

Answer (score 0):

> You can also add extra parameters after the 1st (this) parameter and
>   bind will pass in those values to the original function. Any
>   additional parameters you later pass to the bound function will be
>   passed in after the bound parameters.

So in case of your example:

```
function foo(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b);
  console.log("a:" + a + ", b:" + b);
}

var bar = foo.bind(null, 2);
```

Here we have only passed one parameter after `this` reference parameter and that is for `a`. If you call it like this:

```
bar();// here a is 2 and b is undefined(no parameter passed).

bar(3);// a is 2 and b is 3
```

`bar(3);` is equivalent to :

```
foo.bind(null, 2, 3);
bar();
```

Comment: Please comment to point out if you think answer is not correct. I don't get to know my mistake with that downvote